# How to check for no matches in the loop using Laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following scenario:

```
  @foreach ($driver->delivery as $delivery)<!--loop over all deliveries -->                                                
     @if ($delivery->delivery_date==$whole_week["mon"])
        {{$delivery->city}} , {{$delivery->state}}                        
     @endif
  @endforeach
```

It loops over all deliveries and if delivery is matching day on Monday then I show city and state.

Is there any `blade` way of showing message `no delivery` if the loop produced no matches? Or I need to introduce the `$successful_match` variable where I will store `bool` for successful match? (working example below)

```
<?php $sunDelivery=false; ?>
  @foreach ($driver->delivery as $delivery)<!--loop over all deliveries -->                                                
     @if ($delivery->delivery_date==$whole_week["sun"])
         {{$delivery->city}} , {{$delivery->state}}  
         <? $sunDelivery=true; ?>
    @endif                        
  @endforeach   
{{$sunDelivery ? '' : 'no delivery'}}
```

Comment: Logic works correcltly, I am wondering is there is a 'blade'-way of doing it without using `<?php ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an appropriate syntax to do that. It is discouraged to do it in a view.

The most correct way is to pre-process data and send variable True/False to the view.

Otherwise, you can [extend Blade](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/238/extending-blade-templates) adding a new command or using an extension package like [this one](http://robin.radic.nl/blade-extensions/directives/assignment.html).

**Dirty trick 1:**

Pass `$sunValue` as false to view and set it in this way:

```
@foreach( $driver->delivery as $delivery )
    @if( ($sunDelivery) ? $delivery->delivery_date==$whole_week["sun"] : $sunDelivery=$delivery->delivery_date==$whole_week["sun"] )
    (...)
```

By this way, if `$sunValue` is False (default), `$sunValue` is set to True/False condition before evaluate it, otherwise only condition is evaluated.

IMHO, this dirty trick is more clean than following.

**Dirty trick 2:**

Use Comment/Uncomment:

```
{{--*/ $sunDelivery = False /*--}}
@foreach( $driver->delivery as $delivery )
    @if( $delivery->delivery_date==$whole_week["sun"] )
        {{--*/ $sunDelivery = True /*--}}
        (...)
```

This method works because Blade comments are converted in `<?php /*...*/ ?>`, so above syntax become `<?php /**/ command /**/ ?>`.

---

Note: both codes are tested as working.